# how to get ngif =hide input value in angular 2 forms

Tags: angular

in my form i am showing two files conditionally..

when one is true i am getting the value. but i want to send hidden value field as zero.

my html file

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="block_rent_sold" >
            <label for="Weekly_Rent">Weekly Rent &nbsp;$</label>
            <input type="number" id="Weekly_Rent"
                   class="form-control" value="0"
                   placeholder="Rent Amount"
                   ngModel
                   name="Weekly_Rent" required
                   >
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group" *ngIf="!block_rent_sold" >
            <label for="Rent"> Price &nbsp;$</label>
            <input type="number" id="Weekly_Rent"
                   class="form-control" value="0"
                   placeholder="Property Price"
                   ngModel
                   name="Rent" required
                   >
                   </div>
```

when weekly rent true i want send **Rent** field as zero

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using ***ngIf** use **hidden** for showing control conditionally and maintain it's value.

Please refer following code:

```
<div class="form-group" [hidden]="!block_rent_sold" >
               //your control code
</div>
<div class="form-group" [hidden]="block_rent_sold" >
        //your control code
</div>
```

Hope it helps!!!